# Question regarding js.min files and Xampp

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

I am complete noob and having hard time trying to understand Xampp.
I am changing the html file but change is not applying. It is not visible.

I have this change, adding script tag and implementing some logic with promises

[image]

But when i delete some js.min file then my changes applied but then all the functionality is lost.

[image]

But now the huge plot twist is that when I work on my local machine. Everything works fine. I dont need to delete taoItems.min.js and my changes are applied.

What can I do to apply the changes to my server ?

Comment: Most probably caching. Maybe in the browser, so do a `CTRL F5` to refresh the cache

Comment: I tried that it didnt not work. I even disabled cache

Comment: That looks like a framework, which one?